# Assign signers to Radio group via pdf form field transformations in docusign rest api

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I have a PDF with form fields that I have to upload to docusign via the rest api.

I'm using the PDF form field transformation to transform the PDF fields in to Signature fields and assign them to signers by using wild card labels via composite templates as below.

This works fine for Signature and Date fields but I can't figure out how to assign radio button groups to signers as Radio group does not have a TabLabel property.

This is how the code looks like for Signature and Date fields (I'm using the c# sdk)

```
    Tabs = new Tabs
                {
                    SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> {

                        new SignHere
                        {
                            //use  the wildcard matching id the signer
                            TabLabel = $"_es_:signer{signer.SignerId}\\*"
                        }
                    },
                    DateSignedTabs = new List<DateSigned>
                    {
                        new DateSigned
                        {
                            TabLabel = $"_es_:signer{signer.SignerId}\\*"
                        }
                    },...
```

How do I add the radio group the same way ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   RadioGroupTabs = new List<RadioGroup>
    {
        new RadioGroup
        {
            GroupName = $"_es_:signer{signer.SignerId}\\*"
        }
    },...
```

Comment: Thanks but the RadioGroup does not have a field named `TabLabel`  - or is that a limitation in the C# sdk ?

Comment: oops, sorry, it's called GroupName for RadioGroup. Fixed it now. Please try this